# Aframe - Web VR Firefox support

Tags: aframe

I have build a simple VR scene using A-frame. I have tested this scene in chrome for Android and it is working alright. Two things I have done for this are

1. Install Google VR services
2. enable web vr flag on chrome

**Problem Statement**: Does firefox for android supports web vr?

I have downloaded latest version 61.00 on my android device and trying to access the scene but as soon as I enter VR mode and see in cardboard, the behavior is same as using chrome without web vr flag enabled.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Akki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox for Android does not support WebVR. [Firefox Reality](https://github.com/mozillareality/firefoxreality) will be the best option but it does not support immersive mode (enter vr) at the moment